# How to modify the data in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my project i'm triying to edit a data. The user should modify only one attribute (state)  and if the model is valid the data is saved and and email is send to the address of email who is in clientMail.

Here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GérantRéservationApprove([Bind(Include = "reservation_id, date, nb_persons, RestoId")] Reservation reserv)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(reserv).State = EntityState.Modified;
                if (reserv.state == false)
                {
                    string objet = "Réservation indisponible";
                    string contenu = "Bonjour cher client. Nous venons par ce courriel vous informé que nous ne pouvons donné suite à votre réservation prévu sur le " + reserv.date +". Nous vous prions de nous excuser.";
                    WebMail.Send(reserv.ClientMail, objet, contenu, null, null, null, false, null, null, null, null, null, null);

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("GérantRéservation", "Admin");
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    string objet = "Confirmation de réservation";
                    string contenu = "Bonjour cher client. Nous venons par ce courriel vous informé que votre réservation prévu sur le " + reserv.date +" a été approuvé. Merci d'avoir choisi notre établissement.";
                    WebMail.Send(reserv.ClientMail, objet, contenu, null, null, null, false, null, null, null, null, null, null);

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("GérantRéservation", "Admin");
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("GérantRéservation", "Admin");
        }
```

And here is the view

```
@model MiabéResto.Models.Reservation

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Modifier une réservation";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    
}

<h2>Modification de la réservation</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("GérantRéservationApprove","Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Reservation</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.reservation_id)
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nb_persons, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nb_persons, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nb_persons, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.note_reserv, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.note_reserv, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.note_reserv, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.state, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.state)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.state, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientMail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientMail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientMail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, "UserId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("UserId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RestoId, "RestoId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("RestoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RestoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Valider" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 }

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Retour", "GérantRéservation","Admin")
</div>
```

Only the state attribut is not in readonly, but when it is modify in the view it value don't change. This is the first problem.
The second is this: the execution give this exception

**System.InvalidOperationException : 'Un destinataire doit être spécifié.'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove bind from the action

```
 public ActionResult GérantRéservationApprove ( Reservation reserv)
```